# Getting max value of related table data in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, yii2

I am trying to get next:

I have a table orders. This table has column order_uuid.
I have another table status_history which has all the statuses of each order.

I need to get all the order and the max value of all the statuses of each order.

Example:

order1 has statuses 1,2,3
order2 has statuses 4,5,6

it must return order1, 3      and order2 and 6.

Comment: Have you looked into max()?

Comment: yes. But it return the max value of the entire table values, and I need to get the max status value of each order. Because the order can have a lot of statuses but I need to get only the max of each one

Comment: Which  you do by using `GROUP BY order`. If you want a complete answer you need to provide example input data and expected output as well as the query you have tried. **Add as update to question**.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give us all the needed column names but try something like this:

```sql
SELECT o.ordernumber, max(sh.status)
FROM orders o
JOIN status_history sh ON sh.order_uuid = o.order_uuid
GROUP BY o.ordernumber
```